# Is it possible to create a timer which pauses when stopping at a breakpoint

Tags: javascript, animation, timing

In the past few years, I've moved from using code like `setTimeout` and `setInterval` to using `requestAnimationFrame`. If I want something to happen every 60s, rather than `setTimeout(..., 60000)` I would use `Date` to determine what time it'll be 60s from now, and then check the time every time `requestAnimationFrame` runs. Once the current time passes the target time, run the animation.

However, stopping at breakpoints throws a big wrench in this plan. Let's say I want to use the same approach to trigger some kind of fallback if an event doesn't happen within X seconds. If stopping at a breakpoint takes longer than X seconds, the fallback behavior will be triggered.

Is there some way to create a timer which is aware of when JS has stopped for breakpoints? Perhaps something from t[he Performance API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance)?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is to use the setTimeout function to periodically check whether the desired time has elapsed. This approach should work even if js execution is paused during a breakpoint..

```
let fallbackTimer = null;

function startFallbackTimer(timeout) {
  fallbackTimer = setTimeout(() => {
    // Run fallback behavior
  }, timeout);
}

function resetFallbackTimer(timeout) {
  clearTimeout(fallbackTimer);
  startFallbackTimer(timeout);
}

// Start timer
startFallbackTimer(60000);

// Reset timer whenever event occurs
eventEmitter.on('event', () => {
  resetFallbackTimer(60000);
});
```